# Nativescript Angular: page-router-outlet child of named page-router-outlet is not displaying content

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I've encountered an issue in Nativescript Angular where content of a page-router-outlet is not rendered when it is a child of a named page-router-outlet.

I've created a playground to show the differences between the behavior of a PRO that is a child of the default PRO, and a PRO that is the child of a named (auxiliary) page router outlet.

Here's the url of the playground app https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=3GMdit

Structure is as follows

```
- Root PRO (app component)
  - PRO (Home Component)
    - PRO (Unnamed component) (yellow part in preview)
      - Content (named child component) (gray part in preview)
  - Named PRO (Home Component)
    - PRO (Named Component) (Red part in preview)
      - Content (Unnamed child component) (Orange part in preview)
```

With the above structure, the content that should be rendered in the `page-router-outlet` of the Named component, ie. that is a child of a named page router outlet, is not rendered, and no orange part is shown.

If the PRO of the Named Component is changed to an Angular `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` element, the orange part is rendered.

I am doing something wrong in attempting to render the orange content?

Comment: Page Router Outlet is a complex pice, there are many [open bugs](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+router+label%3Arouter) when it comes to complex & nested outlets. I think the code suppose to work, raising a issue on Github may give you more directions.

Comment: Thank you @Manoj will certainly do